# Replacement for GWT

Tags: java, gwt, client-server

I built an application using GWT in 2012 and it has worked fine until now when a major functionality upgrade is required.
I used GWT because my background is Java and having worked in MVP type projects prior to that it was a good fit.

Today, any problem I encounter and do a  google search for has answers that are posted 2 to 3 years ago ( and in a lot of cases don't solve my own issues ) This is telling me that GWT is being left behind.
Because I built the app primarly as a hobby to learn GWT I feel like I would like to learn a more recent framework when rebuilding my application.
So to narrow it down,  I want to know if there is any suitable more recent alternative to GWT out there that still allows me to code in Java.

I understand this may seem like a broad question where answers will be mainly based on opinion but how else can you pick peoples brains except asking "What is your opinion"  How do I do a,b,c using Java is going to be answered 3 different ways by 3 different people based on their opinion of how it should be done.

Comment: Java Entreprise Edition (a good start for your research [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2097732/1498389)) ! Or any JEE framework, like the well-known Spring :)

Comment: I have dabbled in Spring a while back in my work place.  I figured it would be a bit heavy handed for what I need to do.  Also because I want to use this as a chance to learn a new technology / framework / platform I shyed away from it because I had used it before

Comment: GWT development is still active, but there is a lack of focus on improving the experience for new users of it. Which is unfortunate. That said, it does what it claims to do, and is a fairly mature system. The maturity is one reason why so little appears to be changing, the other is that it evolves on Java timescales, not JS timescales.

Comment: Yeah the last consolidation to debugging with source maps basically made GWT unusable for me: no good debugging support any more. You cannot even inspect static variables easily!! What a disgrace. No source map reversion, I cannot even inspect the original code running in the browser.... wtf? This's absolutely hilarious, but what do you expect from javascript developers. I used GWT to get away from that script kiddie nonsense, and with 2.7 we have all their disadvantages plus then some...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check OpenXava it's easy to use. http://www.openxava.org/ate/gwt-alternative

Comment: I had looked into this.  Didn't want to mention it in OP to see would it pop up as an answer.  Will accept as answer when I give it a quick spin

Answer (score 3):

I have heard about Vaadin (https://vaadin.com/home)

Vaadin is a covering around GWT giving you more flexibility to work and the same time maintaining the GWT like experience.

Otherwise this is a good compilation, you could pick what you might need:

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS

Answer (score 2):

As a long time GWT user I am increasingly drawn to AngularJS. Obviously we're talking JavaScript rather than Java here, but coming from a Java background myself I'm finding JavaScript with AngularJS a decent alternative to GWT.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with GWT per se. Polyglot programming has real costs and there is plenty of activity e.g. on gitter. https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt

New users can use https://github.com/gwtboot to get started and there are modern ui kits  like https://dominokit.github.io/domino-ui-demo/index.html?theme=indigo#home

Since you still want to code in Java and want to learn something new, i would suggest using  "**modern GWT**", i.e. using **elemental2 / j2cl**. You should consider learning to refactor your app to separate your view layer from the underlying ui framework. Avoid the parts that will go away in GWT 3.0 such as RequestFactory

Answer (score 1):

[cuba-platform](https://www.cuba-platform.com/) if you are looking for ready made components and [Web Firm Framework](https://webfirmframework.github.io/) if you are looking for a framework which can be used to [build any UI component](https://youtu.be/fWQvC9uV6Hg). Both are java frameworks to build web ui.

Answer (score 0):

JSF? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces

It's the "official" (part of Java EE) framework for Java web apps. I've used it briefly in the past and was relatively happy with it. I very much prefer it over other frameworks that still rely on JSPs.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend learning either Swing or JavaFX.

Swing has been arround since Java 1.2 and is the more "mature" one.
javaFX is their new "hip" version and was introduced into the JDK at version 7.

Personally I'd go for JavaFX just to be "future-proof".

Comment: Actually, Swing or JavaFX are for desktop application, I think OP is searching for web-based application :)